# Fixing washed-out image transition in a slideshow

Tags: javascript, css

I am making a simple slideshow with images fading in and out. The image transition is done in CSS. I am having some issues of washed-out images during the transition. The problem is particularly visible when using the keyboard and keeping a key down. Below is a very basic example (simply press any key to change images).

Is there an easy fix to this? Ideally, I would like to have something similar to that [website](https://www.manoliscoupe.com/orange-tree-road/2qsunqkhtpjyg9r9mc79ygy30ftos6), which I find much more pleasing to the eye.

I have tried to play with the `transition-timing-function` and different `transition-duration` between the `image` and `.visible` rules in the CSS, without success.

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
const imgCount = imgs.length - 1;
let index = 0;
imgs[index].classList.add('visible');

window.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  imgs[index].classList.remove('visible');
  index = index === imgCount ? 0 : ++index;
  imgs[index].classList.add('visible');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body, figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slideshow {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.visible {
  transition: opacity .3s;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="slideshow">
    <img src="https://uploads6.wikiart.org/images/david-roberts/jerusalem-from-the-mount-of-olives-1847.jpg!Large.jpg">
    <img src="https://uploads8.wikiart.org/images/david-roberts/departure-of-the-israelites-1830.jpg!Large.jpg">
    <img src="https://uploads1.wikiart.org/images/david-roberts/church-of-the-holy-sepulchre-jerusalem-1849.jpg!Large.jpg">
    <img src="https://uploads5.wikiart.org/00333/images/david-roberts/david-roberts-1796-1864-the-inauguration-of-the-great-exhibition-1-may-1851-rcin-407143-royal.jpg!Large.jpg">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `timer` with a 100 millisecond delay with each `keydown event`

> Use a control variable whose value is false with each keydown event
> and the next image cannot be displayed until it is false and its value
> becomes true when the timer time has come.

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
const imgCount = imgs.length - 1;
let index = 0;
imgs[index].classList.add('visible');

var allow = true;

window.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  if (allow) {
    imgs[index].classList.remove('visible');
    index = index === imgCount ? 0 : ++index;
    imgs[index].classList.add('visible');
    allow = false;
    displayTimer(200);
  }
});

var timer;

function displayTimer(sec) {
  var dec = sec - 100;

  if (dec == 0) {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    allow = true;
  } else {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      displayTimer(dec)
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body,
figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slideshow {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.visible {
  transition: opacity .3s;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slideshow">
    <img src="https://uploads6.wikiart.org/images/david-roberts/jerusalem-from-the-mount-of-olives-1847.jpg!Large.jpg">
    <img src="https://uploads8.wikiart.org/images/david-roberts/departure-of-the-israelites-1830.jpg!Large.jpg">
    <img src="https://uploads1.wikiart.org/images/david-roberts/church-of-the-holy-sepulchre-jerusalem-1849.jpg!Large.jpg">
    <img src="https://uploads5.wikiart.org/00333/images/david-roberts/david-roberts-1796-1864-the-inauguration-of-the-great-exhibition-1-may-1851-rcin-407143-royal.jpg!Large.jpg">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. This solution works but makes the transitions less smooth. That's why I tried to play with different `transition-duration` instead.